# GET requests with submit forms using angularjs

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

So after learning a bit of AngularJS I was able to get a controller to call an API and store the results in a variable, which is then displayed on my page (whew...). If I go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/search
```

I see the page with the submit form but without the results, and if I go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/search?query=deep&learning
```

I see the page with the submit form + the results for the "deep & learning" query. The problem is: I have to enter "?query=deep?learning" manually, I'm unable to use the submit form to get there. I use this code:

```
<form name='input' action='#search' method='get'>
  <div class='input-group'>
    <input type='text'
           class='form-control'
           placeholder='Enter query.'
           name='query'>
    <div class='input-group-btn'>
      <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With this submit form, if I enter "deep & learning" in the form, I get to

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/?query=deep&learning#/search
```

How do I change my code so entering "deep & learning" would get me to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/search?query=deep&learning
```

?

Thank you

UPDATE1: code for routes:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .factory('myQuery', ['$http', function($http) {
    var doRequest = function(query) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v0/docs?search=' + query
      });
    };
    return {
      results: function(query) { return doRequest(query); }
    };
  }]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
      controller  : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/search', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/search.html',
      controller  : 'searchController'
    });
});

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // ...
});

myApp.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'myQuery', function($scope, $routeParams, myQuery) {
  myQuery.results($routeParams.query)
    .success(function(data, status, headers) {
      $scope.count = data.count;
      $scope.results = data.results;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: some problem with your router mate! can you paste your router js as well

Comment: @V31 Done... I thought it was a simple problem with my form :)

Comment: let your answer flow in here...curious now :)

Answer (score 0):

It should simply a matter of changing the `action` attribute value to get the URL format you want.

In other words:

```
<form name='input' action='search' method='get'>
```

Note that the destination URI is no longer prefixed with a hash.

When it is prefixed with a hash as you have it at the moment, it's actually equivalent to directing the submission to the root (i.e. `'/'`) using `search` as the page anchor.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work (and I already tried it): it will get me to http://127.0.0.1:3000/search?query=deep&learning and thus an error 404. My "base" page for search is http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/search and I need to get to http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/search?query=deep&learning.

Comment: My bad! The fact you haven't enabled `html5Mode` through `$locationProvider` slipped my mind. Anyway, is there any reason you're not using `ng-submit` and instead choosing to use the `action` and `get` attributes on your form? As it stands at the moment, I don't think Angular routing is catching the submission.